# Don't remove doxygen markup comments from raw source display

Tags: doxygen

If I document my functions in the source code like this:

```
/// return random value between min and max
inline double random(double min, double max){
    return (double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX * (max - min) + min;
}
```

then doxygen removes the description in the raw source display. You can see this for instance here:

http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/MatrixBase_8h_source.html

Whenever there are missing line numbers, doxygen markup commands were deleted. Is there a way to keep them in? I think these comments are helpful remarks to keep even in the raw source display... I couldn't find any flag for this.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this doxygen has the configuration setting: `STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS`

> Setting the STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS tag to YES will instruct doxygen to
>   hide any special comment blocks from generated source code fragments.
>   Normal C, C++ and Fortran comments will always remain visible. The
>   default value is: YES.

So by default the doxygen comments are stripped setting `STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS` to `NO` will retain the comments.